# Filter actions for userroles and building up a menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building up a MVC Razor (.Net) site for the company i work for. Yet i'm still very new to MVC and i was just wondering how to do this.
Actually i have 2 questions but the first one is more important.

And the logged in user is stored in the viewbag.
The user has a value of an emum containing the user's role (Example: Client, Coach, Admin).
How can i make filters on actions for custom roles e.g.

```
[Roles(Coach,Admin)]    
public ActionResult Index(Somemodel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dosomestuff()

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Now secondly this is just for the lazy.
Is it possible to generate menu items from filters
And in addition to also give the roles for whom the menuitem should show up.

Example:

```
[MenuItem]
[Roles(Coach,Admin)]    
public ActionResult Index(Somemodel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dosomestuff()

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Can i make a structure that This will automatically show up in some kind of menu for in this case only the Users that are marked as either coach or admin.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make filters on actions for custom roles e.g.

You could use the `Authorize` attribute which will query the role provider:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Coach, Admin")]
public ActionResult Index(Somemodel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dosomestuff()
    }
    return View();
}
```

> Is it possible to generate menu items from filters

Authorization filters should be used to perform authorization and not build UI. You may consider using HTML Helpers or Partials to generate those menu items. Inside the view you could always verify if the user is in a given role using the following:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Coach"))
{
    <li>This menu will be visible only to users in the Coach role</li>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one Question.. How do i give the user role to MVC?

Comment: That will depend on how and where you are storing your users. If you are using the default membership provider, users are stored in a SQL database which is where you could grant them roles.